# Unresolved link error using JNI to load C# into Java project

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am attempting to load a DLL in my Java project, to allow me to use some code from C#. I made a sample and attempted to implement it in my Java project, however I am stuck receiving the following error when I attempt to run my Java project (Designer) :

```
D:\RPMOpen\svnCobra\conversion\Designer>designer

D:\RPMOpen\svnCobra\conversion\Designer>java -jar Designer.jar "D:/RPMOpen/svnCobra"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: main/Designer.displayHeyLand()V
        at main.Designer.main(Designer.java:491)
```

What I find curious is that I was receiving an error with respect to loading my DLL in my Java project which I managed to fix, and in the following code from my Java project **if I comment out the last line my Designer works fine** now. This suggests to me that my .DLL is in fact loading properly, but really confuses me as to why I am receiving a UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Java project sample code:

```
static {
        System.load("D://RPMOpen/svnCobra/Java/Designer/HeyLand.dll");
        }

    public native void displayHeyLand();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.length == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Conversion location required");
        }



    cobraLocation = args[0];
            INPUT = cobraLocation + "/conversion/src/vb/";
            OUTPUT = cobraLocation + "/conversion/aui/Designer/";
            //System.loadLibrary(cobraLocation + "/conversion/Designer/GetFRXWrapper.dll");
            //String s = getFromFRX();
            //System.out.println(s);

            Designer t = new Designer();
            t.displayHeyLand();
```

Original C# code attempting to be implemented:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CSharpHeyLand
{
    public CSharpHeyLand() { }

    public void displayHeyLand()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey Java, this is C#!", "Sample");
    }
 }
```

Elements from my wrapper, comprising of a C++ source file and two header files:

```
 //Cpp file HeyLand.cpp *******************************************

#include <jni.h>
#include "Java\HeyWork.h"



// managed c++ header containing call to c#
#include "MCPP\HeyLand.h"

// JNI call to managed C++ Class

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_Designer_displayHeyLand  (JNIEnv *jn, jobject jobj) {

    // istantiate the MC++ class.
    HeyLandC* t = new HeyLandC();

    // actual call is made. 
    t->callCSharpHeyLand();
}

//Header file HeyWork.h *******************************************

#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Test1 */

#ifndef _Included_Designer
#define _Included_Designer
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Designer
 * Method:    displayHeyLand
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_Designer_displayHeyLand
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

//Header file HeyLand.h *******************************************

#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "/CSharpHeyLand.netmodule"

using namespace System;

public __gc class HeyLandC
{
    public:
        // provide .NET interop and garbage collecting to the pointer
        CSharpHeyLand __gc *t;
        HeyLandC() {
            t = new CSharpHeyLand();
            // Assign the reference a new instance of the object
        }

     // This inline function is called from the C++ Code
        void callCSharpHeyLand() {
            t->displayHeyLand();
        }
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think I saw the same question yesterday, did you try to remove "MessageBox.Show" sentence and see if it is OK?

Comment: It still isn't okay, and a sample not implemented in my large project worked iwth the message box yesterday.

Comment: try with the process monitor to monitor the java.exe to see how it loads DLLs: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same error several monthes ago. We tried to use a C# DLL from Java, here's what we did:

1. Write a C# DLL.
2. Develop a C++/CLI DLL as a wrapper of the C# DLL, export the functions required.
3. In Java, load the C++/CLI DLL and call the functions through JNI.

Loading the C++/CLI DLL is already OK, just like your case, when executing some code, we encounter the UnsatisfiedLinkError error, we traced it with the [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), it is because that the java exe doesn't find reference C# assemblies.

Unlike the native C++ DLL, the referenced managed assembly is not load immediately when exe starts, [it is loaded as needed](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded), this happens when the [JIT compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.90).aspx) converts MSIL code to native code  at application run time when the code is reached at the first time.  This explains when the error happens when it reaches that line of code.

So to figure out this problem, you can use the process monitor to monitor the java.exe to see how it loading the DLLs. As I observed,the java exe will try find the C# DLL in:

1. First in [global assembly cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx).(GAC). Only strong name assemblies are in GAC.
2. The folder of java.exe.

So if the reference assembly are not in the two places, you will encounter that error.

Comment: So were that the issue, I would have to add my DLL to the GAC as well as the folder of java.exe?

Comment: Also, the strange thing is, my test works standalone. It only produces this error when I input it in my massive Designer.java project which is in eclipse, whereas my standalone test was written in Notepad++ and compiled on the command line. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Either one place is fine. For the second question, it should not matter.

Comment: If it doesn't matter, then I'm incredibly confused as to why the identical code works standalone but not implemented in a larger project compiled in Eclipse, instead of in the command line. Strange. I'll see if strong-naming and adding to GAC works.

Comment: You should use the process monitor to track the file loading activities to find out.

Comment: I am having an incredibly hard time finding my way around the process monitor. Do you happen to have a link or quick explanation as to how to see file loading activities? Seems like there is a lack of resources online.

Comment: you just need to add a filter "process name is java.exe" to filter out other processes, then check the file activities in the log

Comment: Process monitor has confirmed that it actually is finding the .dll succesfully.

Comment: not just that dll, you have to make sure its referred assemblies be found

Comment: If you mean the .netmodule from my C# program, that is being found as well.

Comment: If no missing DLLs, then you have to use Visual studo to attach to java.exe to debug it.

Comment: I am now attempting to do that, the output simply shows java.exe loading a whole bunch of dlls then closing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a DEVPATH environment variable that references to the place where managed DLL is stored. In this case you have to set [developmentMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyshaw37(v=vs.110).aspx) on at [machine.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648964.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) file.